# Can't find where to add GTM body script - pixelyoursite

Tags: wordpress, web, wordpress-theming, google-tag-manager, wp-admin

I'm trying to setup GTM for my wordpress website and I'm using pixelyoursite as my plugin for tracking. The problem is, the GTM scripts that I have are for `head` and `body` while the pixelyoursite only indicates `head` and `footer`. Where can I insert the `body` script from GTM?

[GTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkRPo.png)

[Pixelyoursite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtbDC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just insert it in the footer.

GTM snippet in `<head>` are working for most of the situation. If something wrong then it will use the code in .

Maybe you can add some screenshot to make people in the future better understand the scenario

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion! I already fixed my problem by using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/addfunc-head-footer-code/ instead of Pixelyoursite.